# Storing list of actions in Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, web-applications

I need some advice.  I'm making an app that is a little complicated to learn.  It has a user model.  Once a user signs up, I'd like a modal dialog to appear the first time (and only the first time) he/she access certain pages.  For example, there's a "vote" page and a "create a poll" page, etc.

What's the best way to implement this type of help system?  I thought of adding a column to my user model that can contains a default list of values like "vote,create,share."  When the user accesses the page that corresponds to one of those actions, if the name of the action is still in the list, the modal appears and the name of the action is removed from the list.

Does this sound reasonable?  I know that in a normalized database, you shouldn't store multiple values in a single field.  But it seems crazy to create a table called "actions" and another joining table to relate users to actions.  There are only 4 or 5 things the user can do on the site.

Or is there some other way to do this that I'm missing?  Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: If the set of things that the user might do is completely static and will never change, you shouldn't have too much of a problem denormalising in a manner similar to your suggestion.  However, I'd suggest that the column is either of MySQL's [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set.html) type or else you have multiple columns (one per action) of MySQL's `BOOLEAN` type.

Comment: Please don't use `SET` in a Rails application. It's extremely brittle and introducing a new value into the list requires a schema alteration. Re-building a large table can require significant down-time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make a UserTrigger model that can be used to "trigger" certain actions like this. It would look something like this in practice:

```
<% for_trigger(@user, :first_time_help) do %>
...help content...
<% end %>
```

This method would have a definition approximately like:

```
def for_trigger(model, name)
  if (model.triggers.where(:name => name.to_s).delete_all > 0)
    yield
  end
end
```

A softer version would have a `should_trigger?` and `did_trigger!` method pair, where one would test and the other would actually remove the trigger record. This single-shot one should be good enough for most cases.

You would have a definition in your User model roughly like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :triggers,
    :class_name => 'UserTrigger'
end

class UserTrigger < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You will have to pre-populate these trigger records `after_create` on your User model, or any other models that require it. To re-set the trigger, just re-add the record.